# XML append attribute without creating a variable

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am trying to achieve the following code in one line without declaring a variable. The code will create an XML element, add an attribute and a value and finally append it to the XML document:

```vb
    Dim XMLDoc As New XmlDocument
    Dim XMLRoot As XmlElement
    XMLRoot = XMLDoc.CreateElement("Test1")
    XMLRoot.Attributes.Append(XMLDoc.CreateAttribute("Test2")).Value = "Test3"
    XMLDoc.AppendChild(XMLRoot)
```

I have tried the following but it returns an error: *Boolean cannot be converted to 'XmlNode'.*

```vb
    Dim XMLDoc As New XmlDocument
    XMLDoc.AppendChild(XMLDoc.CreateElement("Test1").Attributes.Append(XMLDoc.CreateAttribute("Test2").Value = "Test3"))
```

This returns error: *Expression does not produce a value.*

```vb
    Dim XMLDoc As New XmlDocument
    XMLDoc.AppendChild(XMLDoc.CreateElement("Test1").SetAttribute("Test2", "Test3"))
```

Comment: Even if you inline variable creation into method call, variable will be created by compiler anyway. By using variable you will make others and later you life easier :). Why you don't want to use temporary variable?

Comment: I am mostly curious on how I would solve it. I can't find a solution to my issue. Would you happen to know a way for me to do that?

Comment: You need to create a variable, because `.AppendChild` method expects a value of type `XmlElement`. If element creation is complicated, wrap it with the method which returns created element and pass it to the `.AppendChild()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are creating new xml document. There are few other options to create xml without introducing "temporary" variables.

XDocument (System.Xml.Linq)

```vb
Dim document As New XDocument(
    new XElement(
        "root",
        new XElement(
            "element",
            new XAttribute("type", "parent")
        )
    )    
)

' Output

' <root>
'     <person type="parent" />
' </root>
```

With XML Literals which is a feature existing only in VB.NET you can do it in more convenient way

```vb
Dim document As XDocument = 
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <root>
        <person type="parent"></person>
    </root>

' Output

' <root>
'      <person type="parent" />
' </root>
```

If you need to append element into already existing xml:

With LINQ to XML

```vb
Dim document As XDocument = XDocument.Load(filepath)

document.Root.Add(new XElement("person", new XAttribute("type", "child")))
```

With XML Literals

```vb
Dim document As XDocument = XDocument.Load(filepath)

document.Root.Add(<person type="child"></person>)
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not like the Library XML especially because of the number of lines you need to create and add elements.  I exclusively use the new Net Library `System.Xml.Linq`.  See code below :

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As New XDocument(New XElement("Test1", New XAttribute("Test2", "Test3")))
    End Sub

End Module
```